# How to use Mongodb Aggregation for querying the records

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation

```
    id:6177cce300093920acc19927
        appointmentDoctor:1
        appointmentPatient:5
        appointmentHospitalName:"ABC"
        appointmentDoctorName:"ABC"
        appointmentPatientPhone:"090078601"
        appointmentPatientName:"ABC"
        relativeAppointment:""
        appointmentAddress:"ABC"
        appointmentFee:"ABC"
        appointmentTime:"2021-11-11T13:00:00+05:00"
        appointmentDate:2021-11-25T00:00:00.000+00:00
        createdAt:2021-10-26T09:39:47.061+00:00
        updatedAt:2021-11-11T09:00:08.755+00:00
        __v:0
        appointmentCity:"ABC"

id:6177cce300093920acc19928
        appointmentDoctor:2
        appointmentPatient:6
        appointmentHospitalName:"ABC"
        appointmentDoctorName:"ABC"
        appointmentPatientPhone:"090078601"
        appointmentPatientName:"ABC"
        relativeAppointment:""
        appointmentAddress:"ABC"
        appointmentFee:"ABC"
        appointmentTime:"2021-11-11T13:00:00+05:00"
        appointmentDate:2021-11-25T00:00:00.000+00:00
        createdAt:2021-10-26T09:39:47.061+00:00
        updatedAt:2021-11-11T09:00:08.755+00:00
        __v:0
        appointmentCity:"ABC"

id:6177cce300093920acc19927
        appointmentDoctor:1
        appointmentPatient:5
        appointmentHospitalName:"ABC"
        appointmentDoctorName:"ABC"
        appointmentPatientPhone:"090078601"
        appointmentPatientName:"ABC"
        relativeAppointment:""
        appointmentAddress:"ABC"
        appointmentFee:"ABC"
        appointmentTime:"2021-11-11T13:00:00+05:00"
        appointmentDate:2021-11-25T00:00:00.000+00:00
        createdAt:2021-10-26T09:39:47.061+00:00
        updatedAt:2021-11-11T09:00:08.755+00:00
        __v:0
        appointmentCity:"ABC"
```

---

I have appointments table and patients table. In appointments table I have stored the patient Id in apppointmentPatient, Now I want to get the unique patients for a doctor, I have filter the appointments for a doctor by  doctorId, but unable to fetch the record of patients because a patient can have more then one appointments for a single doctor, All I want is to get the unique patients array.

Comment: Your sample document does not have any nested objects. Your question is not clear.

Comment: First I want to filter appointments by appointmentDoctor and then filter the data with appointmentPatients. only unique values of appointments Patients